# How to stop core data from syncing to iCloud

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, synchronization, icloud

I have an app which stores images in document.   I am able to stop the app to sync images to iCloud by using

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    }
    return success;
```

I also need to stop core data sync with iCloud too , can somebody explain or provide code on how to do this

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do it. The problem is that the container path for the database is different for both scenarios and you cannot just remove the "use iCloud sync" initialization and continue working offline. You will need to migrate database (in one direction or the other) every time you wish to start or stop syncing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick easy  way to do this.  One way is  to Identify every record in your core data per device with a UUID, then every time when you connect to iCloud store or get update from iCloud, check the existence of any duplicates, and remove them.  You will have to come a with your own algorithm for this.